# gpg sign a file with --detach-sign in CentOS7 with SELinux enabled

Tags: php, gnupg, gpg-signature

My development environment is CentOS 7. **SELinux is enabled in this.**

I am trying to sign a tgz file using gpg command with shell_exec() in my PHP code as below.

```
$signResult = shell_exec("gpg --detach-sig --output signfile.gpg --sign InputFile.tgz 2>&1");
```

but I am getting the below error due to SELinux.

```
Error: gpg: failed to create temporary file `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/share/httpd/.gnupg/.#xxxx.test.com:22680': Permission denied
gpg: Fatal: can't create lock for '/opt/rh/httd24/root/usr/share/httpd/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg'
```

I want to know how to sign a file (tgz file in my case) using gpg command in PHP code which should create a signature file(signfile.gpg) apart from the input file(InputFile.tgz).

or

Is there a way to do it with gnupg package like,

```
$gnupg = new gnupg();
$gnupg->setsignmode(gnupg::GNUPG_SIG_MODE_DETACH);
```

I do not know how to proceed after these steps.

Answer (score 0):

By default GnuPG looks for keyrings in the `$HOME/.gnupg`, and if it is empty then attempts to create basic keyring files. Which fails in this case due to permissions. To override this you shoulde use `--homedir` option.

Also you would not be able to sign until you have some secret key file generated and stored in your keyrings.

Comment: When I disable the SELinux, signing  works fine. but when I enable the SELinux it throws this error message.

Comment: At first look on what is SELinux is it definitely should be the reason as it "SELinux improves server security by restricting and defining how a server processes requests and users interact with *sockets*, network ports, and *essential directories*."